# redirection to another page in another tab by p:link is calling predestroy and initialize of another page

Tags: jsf

I have two controllers extending an abstractController

ActController of @Named and @ViewScopped
GptController of @Named and @ViewScopped

where in the abstractController have:

@inject
@param
double id

and predestroy function

I open gpt-card to edit
when I open act-list where it redirect me to an act-card by p:link
the initialize and predestroy of GptController is being called. Why ?
Why redirection of a page call predestroy of another page

I tried to change p:link to h:link. the same problem.

I also tried to not extend from abstract class. also the same problem.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: View-scoped beans are tied to the specific view they are associated with. Once the user navigates away from this view, the bean will be garbage collected.